# Pasar variables y realizar acciones entre clases en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, clase, método

Estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje C#, utilizando ademas la herramienta VisualStudio, y no logro pasar una variable (BtnColor en el codigo) de una clase a otra, para luego realizar una accion a partir del valor de esa variable. 
Este es el formulario que intento crear en VisualStudio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que al hacer click en el primer boton, cambie el color del mismo a rojo, y en donde dice "Ninguno Seleccionado" (label1) aparezca la palabra "rojo".
Este es el Codigo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace A___CambiarColorBotones
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    protected string BtnColor;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
        BtnColor = "red";
        CambiarColorBoton colorbtn = new CambiarColorBoton();
        colorbtn.CambiarColor(BtnColor);
    }
}
public class CambiarColorBoton:Form1
{
    string c;
    public void CambiarColor(string BtnColor)
    {
        c = BtnColor;
    }
    public void BtnColorCambiar()
    {
        if (c == "red")
        {
            label1 = "Rojo";
        }
    }

}
```

Con este codigo, el error que sale es: 
CS0122 - 'Form.label1' no es accesible debido a su nivel de proteccion.

Comment: Creo que te funcionaría hacerlo con metodos individuales para cada boton, no veo la necesidad de crear una clase.

Comment: Ya vi que te respondieron, pero bueno como estas empezando me gustaría compartirte algo de lo que he aprendido. En la programación es bueno tratar de utilizar la menor cantidad de lineas de código que puedas e intentar que el código sea lo más practico, modulable y legible posible, según lo que me enseñaron a mi ayuda a que tu aplicación procese la información de manera más rápida, en tu caso la diferencia de rapidez en la ejecución es imperceptible porque es pequeña pero para aplicaciones que manejen una gran cantidad de información si es importante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lograr lo que buscas, tenes que pasarle `label1` a la clase que quieras que pueda modificarlo, por ejemplo..

```
  public class CambiarColor
    {
        Label label;
        public CambiarColor(Label label)
        {
            this.label = label;
        }

        public void ModificarColor(string color)
        {
            label.Text = color;
        }
    }
```

Luego para llamar al método `ModificarColor(string color)` sólo instancias `CambiarColor`

```
CambiarColor a = new CambiarColor(label1);
a.ModificarColor("Rojo");
```

De esta manera, vas a tener el resultado que buscas!

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda